# 'Protected Q.' & Close Vote Review

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

This question
[Correct usage of pronoun: “their” vs “its”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5142/correct-usage-of-pronoun-their-vs-its)

is shown as "protected by ЯegDwight ...", suggesting that it has some significance.

Should it list in [Review|Close Votes](https://english.stackexchange.com/review-beta/close#close/7407)?

I think it better not, in spite of it having earned some close votes.

Comment: It's now closed. It's a very early ELU question, and it appears that the standard may have moved somewhat since it was asked. Nowadays it would be closed quite quickly, I think.

Answer (score 5):

Many people take "protected" to mean "significant" in some way, but that's not what it is supposed to mean. "Protected" simply means what the banner says: "we've seen enough poor 'answers' from 1-rep users on this one, thank you very much, we have better things to do than clean up here yet again".

That is completely orthogonal to whether the question is a dupe, or really even on-topic at all.

Comment: Noted. Thank you.

Comment: @Kris: oh, and you are less than 1k away from actually seeing the reason *why* it's protected.

Comment: And doing what I can do reach that. There's still much to learn on ELU.

Comment: @Reg: I seem to have recently gained "protective powers", but as yet I haven't actually used them. Should I take it as gospel that the intended context is *where there are already several low-quality "me too" answers* from new users on a popular question that I don't think is likely to have a definitive "correct" answer?

Comment: @Fum popular questions that are one step short of bikeshedding are obvious candidates, yes. However, less popular questions that do have a definite answer probably account for just as many protects. If an elaborate answer has been sitting accepted for two years, and someone new comes along and posts a half-assed one-liner that adds nothing except typos and lols, and the question gets bumped, and someone else sees it and posts yet another pointless one-liner — we don't really need that. And then of course there are questions about offensive words we protect preemptively as soon as we see them.